# Modals with ellipses

Tags: modal-verbs, ellipsis

> "Who killed him? You?"
>
> "No. Had I been able, I would have but I wasn't, so I didn't."

Is this correct and is there a construction with **could** with a similar meaning?

Comment: In your example you've "deleted" the word ***able*** after ***wasn't*** -
 which is perfectly natural, since it's obvious that *in principle* what you're saying is *[but] I **wasn't able** [to kill him]*. But you could just as well have said *...but I **couldn't** [kill him]*. That switch doesn't depend on having used ***could*** earlier. Note that your *Had I been able* is poetic/archaic/archaic phrasing, best avoided in any normal modern context.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence seems fine to me. Some might prefer including "to" after "able", but I don't think that's necessary or particularly important here. As for a similarly constructed sentence using **could**:

> No. If I could have, I would have, but I couldn't, so I didn't.